# Firefox browser isnt launching parallely with other browsers in selenium grid

Tags: java, firefox, automated-tests, selenium-grid

**Desired Capabilities:**

```
threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
        String nodeURL = "http://localhost:5566/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        //Map<String, Object> firfoxOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        capability.setCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        //capability.setCapability(f, value);
        threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability));
        driver = threadDriver.get();
        return driver;
```

**Node Command**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5566  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=Path\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=Path\IEDriverServer.exe
```

I have created 3 classes(each having 1 method) and trying to launch 3 methods in different browsers. Chrome and IE are launching simultaneously but Firefox is launching after Chrome and IE are done with their execution.

Comment: try to set the "-maxSession" parameter to 3 for your node.

Comment: no..it isnt working..actually after every test method i am closing the browser..so when all the browsers are closed then only firefox is opening up

Comment: Could you please copy your full source code? Maybe it will be easier to help you :)

Comment: The problem here is more than likely your node configuration as peetya has eluded to. Try setting -maxSession and maxInstances. The node may be restricting the number of instances as well as the numberof sessions. Here is the reference, if you need more information: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2